# detect touch on Two different Elements

Tags: jquery, dom, cordova, multi-touch

Using phonegap, jquery.
Is it possible to detect touches on two different elements at the same time ?

I'm creating something that requires two images ( button-left and button-right ) to be pressed
at the same time before another event it triggered.

The following is not an exhaustive list of code, but should provide insight into what im trying to achieve

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stopwatch.js"></script>

<script>
    var w = new Stopwatch(updatedisplay, 50);
    var onoff = false;

    $("#button-left, #button-right").unbind("touch",begin);

    function begin() {
        onoff = true;
        w.start();
    }

    function end() {
        w.stop();
        onoff = false;
    }       

    function updatedisplay(watch) {
        var mills = parseInt(watch.getElapsed().milliseconds/10);
        if(mills<10) {
            millis = '0'+mills;
        } else {
            millis = mills;
        }
        document.getElementById('counterValue').innerHTML = watch.toString() + "." + millis;
    }

    function reset() {
        w.stop();
        onoff = false;
        document.getElementById('counterValue').innerHTML = "00:00:00.00";
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
  <div id="counterValue">
    00:00:00.00
  </div>
  <div id="button-left"></div>
  <div id="button-right"></div> 
</body>
```

:::::  CREATED THIS FIX ::::: A BIT UGLY BUT IT WORKS BRILLIANTLY :::::

I found another way around, now this might be a bit ugly.. but it works well ...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                          
       document.getElementById('button-left').addEventListener('touchstart', nofunc(e), false);
       document.getElementById('button-right').addEventListener('touchstart', nofunc(e), false);
    });

    function vala(val) {
        av = val;
        checkvals();
    }
    function valb(val) {
        bv = val;
        checkvals();
    }
    function checkvals() {
        if(av == 1 && bv == 1) {
            if(onoff == false) {
                begin();
            } else {
                end();
            }
        }
    }

   <div id="button-left" ontouchstart="vala(1)" ontouchend="vala(0)">&nbsp;</div>
   <div id="button-right" ontouchstart="valb(1)" ontouchend="valb(0)">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as above, i found a way to do what i needed... a bit of "reading of manuals" and i came up with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {                          
   document.getElementById('button-left').addEventListener('touchstart', nofunc(e), false);
   document.getElementById('button-right').addEventListener('touchstart', nofunc(e), false);
});

function vala(val) {
    av = val;
    checkvals();
}
function valb(val) {
    bv = val;
    checkvals();
}
function checkvals() {
    if(av == 1 && bv == 1) {
        if(onoff == false) {
            begin();
        } else {
            end();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean `unbind` because `detach` is something else it will remove the element from the DOM, to unbind the event there is `unbind`

```
$("#btn1, #btn2").unbind("touch");
```

Update

change the orrder in which you are including the js files the jquery.js has to be loaded first then the other liberaries that are using it, secondly i have removed the `var` from the `w` and `onoff` to make them global scope, thirdly i have removed the `onbodyload` instead bind the touch event in the ready handler as shown below, try

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.stopwatch.js"></script>

<script>
    w = new Stopwatch(updatedisplay, 50);
    onoff = false;

    function begin() {
        onoff = true;
        w.start();
    }

    function end() {
        w.stop();
        onoff = false;
    }       

    function updatedisplay(watch) {
        var mills = parseInt(watch.getElapsed().milliseconds/10);
        if(mills<10) {
            millis = '0'+mills;
        } else {
            millis = mills;
        }
        document.getElementById('counterValue').innerHTML = watch.toString() + "." + millis;
    }

    function reset() {
        w.stop();
        onoff = false;
        document.getElementById('counterValue').innerHTML = "00:00:00.00";
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#button-left, #button-right").bind("touch",begin);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="counterValue">
    00:00:00.00
  </div>
  <div id="button-left"></div>
  <div id="button-right"></div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks John, tried to implement that with the handler 'begin' - $("#button-left, #button-right").bind("touch", begin);  this didnt have the desired effect, im developing for iPad, using phoneGap and jquery, the function is placed in device onready, and it triggers the begin event without anything being touched. :(

Comment: ok i know nothing about phoneGap so help me understand that `touch` is an event and `begin` is also an event?

Comment: begin is a function i have created to start a timer. ... should the "touch" be replaced with the function 'begin' then ?

Comment: nope thats fine, just wanted to clarify, can you edit your question and add the code you are working with?

Comment: hi john, thanks, the touch event doesnt seem to trigger anything, i changed it to click, and the begin functions runs if either element is touched on the iPad, which is half way there :) ... the begin event must only trigger if both elements are pressed at the same time...

Comment: Is "touch" specific to a certain version of jquery and above ?

Comment: @Deano sorry pal i have no idea but `touch` has something to do with the mobile version of jquery, i think you will have to include jquery mobile too, never worked with the mobile devices ...

Comment: Gonna try tomorrow.. but I need to relax, open a tinny and unplug .. Cheers John :)

Comment: John, thanks for helping before... i've added a fix in my original question :D

Comment: you can answer your own question so in future it can help others